# Data in DataSet not show up in reportviewer which showed when run debugging

Tags: c#, reportviewer

As title, the reportviewer show result correctly when I run on debugging. But when I deploy it to website, it didn't show any data in the report (all the header, parameters show correctly). 
 What had I miss?

Here is my code:

```
rptViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportDataSource rptData = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
LocalReport r = new LocalReport();
r.ReportPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "~/ReportForm/LectureReport.rdlc");
r.DataSources.Add(rptData);
ReportParameter p = new ReportParameter("Title", txtName.Text);
rptViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p });
rptViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptData);
rptViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/ReportForm/LectureReport.rdlc");
rptViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: I find these kind of cases always funny. It is either something so simple that you miss it or there is threading involved so when you actually hit the breakpoint the other thread does the job but when you run it without breakpoint it doesn't.

Comment: Try adding `rptViewer1.DataBind();` before `rptViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();` and check if that work.

Comment: no result. Will ajaxtoolkit have impact with this situation?